# Error Sending Bulk Calendar Appointments Dynamically Using EWS and C#

Tags: c#, calendar, exchangewebservices

I'm developing an outbound call system that shows the user the next company to call with a means to add an appointment for a selected sales rep.

I initially programmed the appointment to be sent in real time as the user saves the current data and move to the next lead. However, there was a significant delay while the appointment was being sent to the email account on Office 365. So I decided to create a small app to send them in batch every 15 minutes.

This works great for the first three appointments, but then I get an error on the 4th appointment:

> The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

I'm suspecting this is something like a hosting company stopping a mailbox from being used for bulk email and there is a limit. Is there something within EWS to allow more than three at a time? Or do I need to amend my code?

Here is my code for sending the appointments:

```
const string o365Server = "mydomain.co.uk";

var appointmenntList = AppointmentList.GetAppointnmetsToSend();
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();

foreach (var appointment in appointmenntList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(appointment.IntLeadID);

    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(appointment.StrSalesRepEmail, apointment.StrSalesRepEmailPassword, o365Server);
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(appointment.StrSalesRepEmail, RedirectionCallback);

    Appointment app = new Appointment(service);

    app.Subject = "ASH Waste Appointment with " + appointment.StrLeadAppointmentContact;
    app.Body = appointment.StrLeadAppointmentNotes;
    app.Start = appointment.DtLeadAppointmentDate;
    app.End = app.Start.AddHours(1);
    app.Location = appointment.StrLeadAppointmentLocation;
    app.RequiredAttendees.Add(appointment.StrSalesRepEmail);
    app.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60;
    app.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
    Console.WriteLine(appointment);
}

static bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
{
    return url.ToLower().StartsWith("https://");
}
```

I could set the app to do only three at a time and run the app every 2 minutes. Although this would be enough for our sales team, it is limiting the operation.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Here's the full error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll

and it occurs on this line of code:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl(appointment.StrSalesRepEmail, RedirectionCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can batch 4 calendar items when using the CreateItems method instead. Have you tried that? Here's some sample code.

```
   public static Collection<ItemId> BatchCreateCalendarItems(ExchangeService service)
    {
        // These are unsaved local instances of an Appointment object.
        // Despite the required parameter of an ExchangeService object (service), no call
        // to an Exchange server is made when the objects are instantiated.
        // A call to the Exchange server is made when the service.CreateItems() method is called.

        Appointment appt1 = new Appointment(service);
        Appointment appt2 = new Appointment(service);
        Appointment appt3 = new Appointment(service);
        Appointment appt4 = new Appointment(service);

        // Set the properties for a single instance appointment
        appt1.Subject = "Appt1";
        appt1.Body = "Appt1";
        appt1.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        appt1.End = appt1.Start.AddHours(3);
        appt1.Location = "My office";
        appt1.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30;

        // Set the properties for a single instance appointment
        appt2.Subject = "Appt2";
        appt2.Body = "Appt2";
        appt2.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        appt2.End = appt1.Start.AddHours(4);
        appt2.Location = "My office";
        appt2.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30;

        // Set the properties for a single instance appointment
        appt3.Subject = "Appt3";
        appt3.Body = "Appt3";
        appt3.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        appt3.End = appt1.Start.AddHours(5);
        appt3.Location = "My office";
        appt3.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30;

        // Set the properties for a single instance appointment
        appt4.Subject = "Appt4";
        appt4.Body = "Appt4";
        appt4.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        appt4.End = appt1.Start.AddHours(6);
        appt4.Location = "My office";
        appt4.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 30;

        // Add the appointment objects to a collection
        Collection<Appointment> calendarItems = new Collection<Appointment>() { appt1, appt2, appt3, appt4 };

        // Instantiate a collection of item ids to populate from the values that are returned by the Exchange server.
        Collection<ItemId> itemIds = new Collection<ItemId>();

        // Send the batch of appointment objects.
        // Note that multiple calls to the Exchange server may be made when appointment objects have attachments.
        // Note also that the item collection passed as the first parameter to CreateItems will have their ids set on return.
        ServiceResponseCollection<ServiceResponse> response = service.CreateItems(calendarItems,
                                                                                  WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,
                                                                                  MessageDisposition.SendAndSaveCopy,
                                                                                  SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
        if (response.OverallResult == ServiceResult.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("All appointments and meetings sucessfully created.");
        }

        // Collect the item ids from the created calendar items.
        foreach (Appointment appt in calendarItems)
        {
            itemIds.Add(appt.Id);
        }

        int counter = 1;
        // Show the ids and errors for each message
        foreach (ServiceResponse resp in response)
        {
            // Note that since item ids are long, show only 5 characters.
            Console.WriteLine("Result (message {0}), id {1}: {2}", counter, itemIds[counter - 1].ToString().Substring(0, 5), resp.Result);
            Console.WriteLine("Error Code: {0}", resp.ErrorCode);
            Console.WriteLine("ErrorMessage: {0}\r\n", resp.ErrorMessage);

            counter++;
        }
        // Return the collection of item ids
        return itemIds;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm intrigued to know why there is a limit. What's actually blocking/stopping theoretically sending infinite appointments?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it isn't that you're getting blocked from sending a specific number of appointments, it's that Autodiscover is failing. That error is one that the EWS Managed API likes to return for all kinds of scenarios, so it doesn't tell me for sure why it is failing. It could be a temporary network issue, or it could be that the Autodiscover servers are throttling you. I'm not sure offhand if Autodiscover does any throttling, but it's certainly possible.

To see why it's failing, you could [enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dd633676%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) with all of the Autodiscover-related trace flags turned on and see what kinds of errors are coming back.

Comment: I will give that a go. Running the code for three appointements every two minutes works without error, but that a bit of a fudge! Thank you.